# Adding a recurring event in Google Calendar doesn't save the entire series

Tags: google-calendar

I've created and published [a recurring event in Google Calendar](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE&tmeid=b3FuNWdkOWJsNDYwOW9hbHR0ZWNxZG91ZGdfMjAxNjAxMjRUMDQzMDAwWiB1NjU4ZjFqbzdyYjYxcGZwZ2FiN2VmdHJoc0Bn&tmsrc=u658f1jo7rb61pfpgab7eftrhs%40group.calendar.google.com). However, if someone adds the event, they get only the upcoming event, not the entire recurring series.

Is there a way I can make Google Calendar publish the event so that when someone adds the event to the calendar, they get the entire recurring series?